# Вывести количество поставок в главный склад после запасных

Tags: mysql, sql

мне нужно посчитать количество поставок за месяц в 'запасные склады' и в 'главный', если товар с item_id был доставлен вначале в запасной и только потом в главный.

Данные

| id | date_traf | item_id | storage_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-12 00:00:00 | 100 | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-03-13 00:00:00 | 100 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-03-15 00:00:00 | 101 | 1 |
| 4 | 2021-03-18 00:00:00 | 101 | 3 |
| 5 | 2021-04-10 00:00:00 | 200 | 2 |
| 6 | 2021-04-11 00:00:00 | 200 | 1 |
| 7 | 2021-05-06 00:00:00 | 100 | 2 |

Результат, который ожидается

| date | count_reserve_storage | count_main_storage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2003 | 2 | 1 |
| 2004 | 1 | 1 |
| 2005 | 1 | 0 |

Даже если после отправки в запасной склад было 20 отправлений товара в главный, то считается как 20, а не 1

[Вот структура таблицы и мой запрос, который я написал](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edc722/1)

Comment: Как колонка `date` результата соотносится с таблицей данных? Как отличить основной склад от запасного? Где в таблице указано количество товара?

Comment: @ArchDemon Колонка date это DATE_FORMAT(tr.date_traf, '%y%m'). Чтобы понимать где за какой месяц подсчитывается. В данном вопросе можно опустить количество товара. На SQL Fiddle сделал дамп. Основной склад с storage_id = 1, остальные - запасные